# Finding the 3rd point of a 3D triangle

Tags: python, 3d

We are given points to a 3D triangle and 2 points of a new 3D triangle in a text file. We need to find the third point of the new triangle so that it is the same size as the original 3D triangle and print the point (C1) on screen.

The provided text file would look something like this
A  2.00  0.0 5.00
B  5.0  0  2.5
C  1.5  0.  2.0
A1  1.00 12.00  8.
B1  1.  15.90512  8.0
END

Here is a more visual description of the problem [example visuals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/owQG4.png)

Our professor provided an example of a student's attempt at this problem (I apologize for the formatting and his enthusiastic use of markers).
[solution attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QZOZ.png)

edit: The triangle is on the XZ plane and I've managed to get the data from the text files put them in lists so far.

Comment: This is not enough information to specify the new triangle. It's the same as if you tried to describe the original triangle with two of its vertices and all of the side lengths - you only specified one side exactly, and you can rotate the triangle around the axis of that side without changing any side lengths.

Comment: @Dikaros, you should show a reasonable effort to solve this yourself. See [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Comment: The triangle is on the XZ plane, sorry for not specifying. I've gotten as far as getting the data from the txt files and putting them in lists, I'm just genuinely stumped on how to proceed forward.